# Apache storm workers not starting

Tags: apache-storm

The storm release is `1.0.1`. My nimbus and supervisor are running. When I submit a ExclamationTopology that in `storm-starter`, the worker is not starting and there isn't a `worker.log`.

I find the error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/363f8.png) from supervisor.log.

Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Comment: Are you using zookeeper?

Comment: yes . I have resolved the issue.It is caused by error configuration. thank you for attention

Comment: @wendyhusband could you please update about which part of the configuration has gone wrong?